# show only user with at least one entry per month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, let's say one is called `User` and the other one is called `Data`

Every `User` has many many entries in the `Data` table.

The `Data` table has the `UserID` and `Dates` included.

I would like to make a SQL query where I only get users with at least one entry per month in year 2019.

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Always include sample data and expected results at a minimum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really mention your database type. Treat this more like pseudo-code for now. But if you update your question, I can update my answer.

```sql
SELECT      userID,
            YEAR(Dates),
            COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(Dates))
FROM        Data
WHERE       YEAR(Dates) = 2019
GROUP BY    UserId,
            YEAR(Dates) 
HAVING      COUNT(DISTINCT MONTH(Dates))=12
```

Since you are looking only at the year 2019, you can exclude it from the `GROUP BY` clause. If you need to adjust the minimum entries for `MONTH`, I would suggest:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT    userID,
            MONTH(Dates) as [month],
            COUNT(*) as TotalEntriesPerMonth
  FROM      Data
  WHERE     YEAR(Dates) = 2019
  GROUP BY  UserId, MONTH(Dates) 
  HAVING    COUNT(*)>=5
)
SELECT      userID 
FROM        CTE
GROUP BY    userID 
HAVING      COUNT([month]) = 12
```

Comment: What would I need to change if I would like to have shown only userIDs with 5 entries per month?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you are asking, but your query may be like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Data(UserId int,Dates date)
INSERT INTO Data(UserId,Dates) VALUES(1,'2020/04/28'),(1,'2020/04/29'),(2,'2020/04/29')

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT UserId,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MONTH(Dates),UserId  ORDER BY UserId) AS rn FROM Data)
SELECT Distinct UserId FROM CTE WHERE rn >=1
```